# How to install multiple individual led strips?

Tags: lighting, led

I have started my final year in interior design and I really want to buy some LED strip lighting to light up my scale models to give them a much more lifelike appearance for photos.

I wouldn't really need longer than 1m for this, but I will probably want to cut them up into individual strips. My issue is what do I do with the strips after they have been snipped? Will they all need their own individual power supply, or could they connect to an individual one?

If anyone would be able to shed any light on this id greatly appreciate it, and if you could possibly list items I'd need?

Answer (score 1):

I have used these inexpensive LED tape lights from Amazon.com with very good success.
You can cut them down to as small as 4" pieces, and use connectors to get wire leads to connect to a driver. You'll need some low-voltage wiring to go between the tape ends and the driver. You have to calculate how much wattage you are putting on each driver, but they do come in several sizes so you can potentially put a lot on a one driver.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Links: 
[http://www.amazon.com/LEDwholesalers-Flexible-300xSMD3528-Adhesive-2026WH/dp/B002Q8V8DM/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1413122307&sr=8-3&keywords=led+tape](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002Q8V8DM)

[http://www.amazon.com/Ledwholesalers-Suppply-Driver-Transformer-Output/dp/B0034GUEY4/ref=sr_1_16?ie=UTF8&qid=1413122307&sr=8-16&keywords=led+tape](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0034GUEY4)

[http://www.amazon.com/Estone-Connector-Adapter-Single-Welding/dp/B00GTGLCXI/ref=pd_bxgy_hi_img_z](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GTGLCXI)